# Check if value is in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables: "Person" and "Member". A member is always a person but a person is not always a member.

I want to get a list of all the persons who are not members.

I tried to do it this way but no luck:

```
var NonMembers = PersonsDB.GetAll().Where(x => !Members.Contains(x));
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What's the relation between `Person` and `Member` table?

Comment: Are you using linq-to-sql? linq-to-entities? Please tag appropriately. What errod you get on your current approach?

Comment: Person != Member in any case, so `!Members.Contains(Person)` will always be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some foreign key (like `PersonId`) in your `Member` table (you have to) and you can compare it with Id of `Person` like this:

```
var NonMembers = 
                PersonsDB.GetAll().Where(x => !Members.Any(y=>y.PersonId==x.Id));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var NonMembers = PersonsDb.GetAll().Except(Members);
```

Comment: You beat me by 1 second D:

Comment: That assumes that the `Person` and `Member` tables are the same type, which is usually not the case in databases.

Comment: @AndersAbel that assumes that you have duplicate data in tables Person and Member, which is hopefully not the case in databases. EDIT: oh wait, OP mentioned that this is actually the case.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Exactly. The Q is not exactly clear on how the tables are related, but it should be with a foreign key, which translates to a navigation property in linq.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the `Except()` extension?

```
var nonMembers = PersonsDB.GetAll().Except(Members);
```

It's almost plain English.

**EDIT**

Assuming that

- `PersonsDB.GetAll()` returns an `IEnumerable<Person>`
- `Members` is an `IEnumerable<Member>`
- `Member` extends `Person`:

you'll need to write your own comparer:

```
public class IsPersonMemberComparer : EqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public override bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        var maybeMember = x;
        var definitelyMember = (Member) y;

        // test whether x and y are the same person
        return maybeMember.SocialSecurityNumber == definitelyMember.SocialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

---

Now specify this comparer when testing for equality.

```
var comparer   = new IsPersonMemberComparer();
var nonMembers = PersonsDB.GetAll().Except(Members, comparer);
```

Comment: That assumes that the Person and Member tables are the same type, which is usually not the case in databases.

Comment: @AndersAbel I thought about it some more. The original specification is just horrible to begin with. There's no clean solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a navigation property (corresponding to a database foreign key) you can check it that is null:

```
var NonMembers = PersonsDB.GetAll().Where(p => p.Member == null);
```